# Error 409 with Python Selenium webdriver on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I made a python script with selenium webdriver that works very well on my computer, with and without headless option.
I tries to run it from an ubuntu server, and that doesn't work. 
It works up to a point (the login works well) then it get an error 409. (I made a screenshot to see the error).

Any Idea ?

Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import os


class Chrome(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(
        self,
        executable_path="chromedriver",
        port=0,
        options=None,
        service_args=None,
        desired_capabilities=None,
        service_log_path=None,
        chrome_options=None,
        timeout=30,
        download_path='/home/me/Téléchargements',
    ):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.download_path = download_path
        for f in os.listdir(download_path):
            os.remove(os.path.join(download_path, f))
        super(Chrome, self).__init__(
            executable_path,
            port,
            options,
            service_args,
            desired_capabilities,
            service_log_path,
            chrome_options,
        )
        self.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
        params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_path}}
        self.execute("send_command", params)

    def wait(self, css):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self, self.timeout).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css))
            )
        except TimeoutException:
            print("timeout " + css)
            browser.quit()
            return False
        return True

    def find_css(self, value=None):
        if not self.wait(value):
            exit()
        return self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value)


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument('--headless')
option.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
option.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

browser = Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", chrome_options=option, timeout=15)
browser.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
browser.get("https://entreprise.pole-emploi.fr/accueil/")
browser.find_css('.eupopup-button.eupopup-button_1').click()
browser.find_css("#dropdownMenu2").click()
browser.find_css(".menu-link-entreprise").click()
browser.find_css("#identifiant").send_keys("USERNAME")
browser.find_css("#password").send_keys("PASSWORD")
browser.find_css("#submit").click()
browser.find_css("#token-input-champsMultitagQuoi").send_keys('"dessinateur projeteur" "autocad" "inventor"')
browser.find_css("#token-input-champsMultitagOu").send_keys("seine-maritime")
browser.find_css("#champsMultitagOuDivAutocomplete .DEPARTEMENT").click()
browser.find_css("#lancerRechercheCv").click()
browser.save_screenshot('screen.png')
print(browser.find_css('h1.title').text)
browser.quit()
```

The "screen.png" file on my computer :
[image]

The "screen.png" file on server :
[image]

Output on server:
    timeout h1.title

Comment: Update the question with your _code trials_ and _error stack trace_

Comment: I added code. There isn't stacktrace since it's not a python exception

Comment: At which line do you see the error?

Comment: after browser.find_css("#lancerRechercheCv").click(), then I save the screen, then "print(browser.find_css('h1.title').text)" doesn't find the node.

Answer (score 0):

It seems be fixed. I removed doublequotes in keywords (replace '"dessinateur projeteur" "autocad" "inventor"' by 'dessinateur projeteur autocad inventor') and its works well on both (computer and server).
But without doublequotes, I lose relevance on results...
It's weird, maybe issue with character encoding ?